# Incorrect Data Structure for Appending Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have 6 donut charts, where the top half represent 5 cities in the North of England, and the bottom 3 representing 5 cities of South England.

Each chart represents either employment, unemployment, or other. The canvas has been split into 3 svgs, the first one employment data, the second unemployment and the third other. I'm happy with the layout, but i have the feeling that the structure of the data can be improved.

I'm struggling to append text (it's values) to the visual (everything i try isn't working), but i have a suspicion that it's because each data set is an array of it's own, rather than grouping it one giant data structure entitled data, or whatever.

However, i'm unsure if is the right approach for what i need? Or is what i have now suffice and i'm missing something to append it's values?

I haven't included any code to apply the text, as i think it is the data structure which is wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Donuts</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<style>
  .container1 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .container2 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(400px, 0px);
  }
  
  .container3 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container1" id="svg1"></div>
  <div class="container2" id="svg2"></div>
  <div class="container3" id="svg3"></div>
  <script>
    var employed1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 54.63
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 62.19
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 55.62
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 60.50
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 59.03
    }];

    var employed2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 65.29
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 66.72
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 62.87
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 67.80
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 67.36,
    }];

    var unemployed1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 15.52
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 6.96
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 9.76
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 10.71
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 5.33
    }];

    var unemployed2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 5.33
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 5.51
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 8.50
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 5.17
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 5.44
    }];

    var other1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 29.85
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 30.85
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 34.62
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 28.79
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 33.76
    }];

    var other2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 29.38
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 27.77
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 28.63
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 27.03
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 27.30
    }];

    const NE = ["Bradford City", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Sheffield"];

    var colorNE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(NE)
      .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

    const SE = ["Brighton", "Bristol", "Luton", "Milton Keynes", "Southampton"];

    var colorSE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(SE)
      .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"]);

    var mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie = d3.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.Percentage
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
      });

    var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(100)
      .outerRadius(135)
      .padAngle(.02)
      .padRadius(50);

    draw("svg1", employed1);
    draw("svg1", employed2);
    draw("svg2", unemployed1);
    draw("svg2", unemployed2);
    draw("svg3", other1);
    draw("svg3", other2);

    function draw(selector, data) {

      var arcData = mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie(data);

      var svg = d3.select("#" + selector)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 391)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(200, 240)");

      svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          var result = null;

          if (NE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
            result = colorNE(d.data.City);
          } else if (SE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
            result = colorSE(d.data.City);
          } else {

            result = "white";
          }
          return result;
        })
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .attr('d', arcGenerator);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: What i'm aiming for]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...I have a suspicion that it's because each data set is an array of it's own.

Not at all. The data structure right now is actually the correct one: each donut has its own data as an inner array. Therefore, the same way you used `arcData` to draw the donuts, use it to print the labels:

```
var labels = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(arcData)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text(function(d){
        return d.value
    });
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Donuts</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<style>
  .container1 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .container2 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(400px, 0px);
  }
  
  .container3 {
    width: 355px;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translate(800px, 0px);
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container1" id="svg1"></div>
  <div class="container2" id="svg2"></div>
  <div class="container3" id="svg3"></div>
  <script>
    var employed1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 54.63
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 62.19
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 55.62
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 60.50
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 59.03
    }];

    var employed2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 65.29
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 66.72
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 62.87
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 67.80
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 67.36,
    }];

    var unemployed1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 15.52
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 6.96
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 9.76
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 10.71
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 5.33
    }];

    var unemployed2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 5.33
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 5.51
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 8.50
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 5.17
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 5.44
    }];

    var other1 = [{
      City: 'Bradford City',
      Percentage: 29.85
    }, {
      City: 'Leeds',
      Percentage: 30.85
    }, {
      City: 'Liverpool',
      Percentage: 34.62
    }, {
      City: 'Manchester',
      Percentage: 28.79
    }, {
      City: 'Sheffield',
      Percentage: 33.76
    }];

    var other2 = [{
      City: 'Brighton',
      Percentage: 29.38
    }, {
      City: 'Bristol',
      Percentage: 27.77
    }, {
      City: 'Luton',
      Percentage: 28.63
    }, {
      City: 'Milton Keynes',
      Percentage: 27.03
    }, {
      City: 'Southampton',
      Percentage: 27.30
    }];

    const NE = ["Bradford City", "Leeds", "Liverpool", "Manchester", "Sheffield"];

    var colorNE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(NE)
      .range(["#A8A7A7", "#2F9599", "#E8175D", "#474747", "#CC527A"]);

    const SE = ["Brighton", "Bristol", "Luton", "Milton Keynes", "Southampton"];

    var colorSE = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(SE)
      .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D"]);

    var mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie = d3.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.Percentage
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.City.localeCompare(b.City);
      });

    var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(100)
      .outerRadius(135)
      .padAngle(.02)
      .padRadius(50);

    draw("svg1", employed1, "Employed");
    draw("svg1", employed2, "Employed");
    draw("svg2", unemployed1, "Unemployed");
    draw("svg2", unemployed2, "Unemployed");
    draw("svg3", other1, "Other");
    draw("svg3", other2, "Other");

    function draw(selector, data, title) {

      var arcData = mentalHealthAndAlcoholPie(data);

      var svg = d3.select("#" + selector)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 391)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(200, 240)");

      var slices = svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
          var result = null;

          if (NE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
            result = colorNE(d.data.City);
          } else if (SE.indexOf(d.data.City) >= 0) {
            result = colorSE(d.data.City);
          } else {

            result = "white";
          }
          return result;
        })
        .style("stroke", "white")
        .attr('d', arcGenerator);

      var labels = svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("text-shadow", "0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + arcGenerator.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.value
        });
        
      var titleText = svg.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "14px")
        .text(title);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: As I don't know what colours you'll have I'm printing the values in a black font with a white shadow... not the best design option, maybe.

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense as it's not data that should be in a hierarchy. If i wanted to display the data of each data structure in the centre of each donut, would that be as simple as creating a new var labels, and replacing the return d.value with return d.name? Or would that produce the names of the city? Which isn't what i want

Comment: An image has been added to the description

Comment: @GeorgeGilliland There is nothing in your data that could tell the code the type of data to each donut. However, you can pass it as an argument: check the snippet again.